# Time Interval to execute trigger

Tags: salesforce

I have trigger to delete records which execute after I change the status. Is it possible to delete the records after some 10 mins after I change the status.

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes exactly im not sure, but you can delay it for an hour using time based triggers in a workflow rule.
In your trigger, instead of deleting a record, mark a boolean field "For Delete" as true, and make a worflow rule that, when that field is set to true fires a time based action 1 hour after workflow activation, marking a new field, "deleting" and a new trigger on the same object to delete any record that has that checkbox filled.

Comment: Thanks Aldo. I will give try with this.

Comment: Not sure if update trigger can decide to delete the record... Maybe it needs `@future` action.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer I'd like to point you to help related to batch jobs on salesforce. You could have a scheduled task running say every 10 minutes, checking if there's something to delete (and maybe lastModifiedDate is ealier than 10 mins ago) and wiping it out.

Or you can use `System.scheduleBatch()` call to put given job in the queue of future executions only once (so it wouldn't be running all the time, only when you queued it from your trigger).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm